# Text formatting difference

Tags: windows-7, awk, windows-xp, cygwin

I get 2 different results for this line in Cygwin.  In XP, columns (the correct output) and Win7 all on one long line

```
awk '{$0=sprintf("%.1f%.1f%4s", $1,$2,$3);gsub(/ /,"0");gsub(/\./,"")}1' /cygdrive/e/$1.txt > /cygdrive/e/$1.bod
```

Thanks

**Input: (35030035.txt)**

```
  4.65   2.38   15
  4.71   3.36  775
  3.52   3.03   53
  4.05   3.33   71
  3.22   2.99  346
```

**XP output: (35030035.bod)** *This is correct output*

```
47240015
47340775
35300053
40330071
32300346
```

**Win7 output:(35030035.bod)**

```
4724001547340775353000534033007132300346
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the line terminators are messed up. Try explicit `\n` in your `sprintf` function.

**`sprintf("%.1f%.1f%4s\n", $1,$2,$3)`**

or instead of `1` do a `print $0`.

```
awk {$0=sprintf("%.1f%.1f%4s", $1,$2,$3);gsub(/ /,"0");gsub(/\./,"");print $0}'
```

Alternative use `RS` variable of `awk` to set the new lines.